# How to Protect My Configuration File

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, configuration

I am writing an SQL Server application in C# built in Visual Studio.  It is a Windows Forms Application. The program will be installed on the network where users will run it.

The problem I am struggling with is how to manage the configuration file.  It has the server username and password there for all to see.  I tried Click Once and an encryption scheme but they both required the programs to run on the computer the program was running from.  It failed when I tried to run it from a workstation.  This is different from [How do I avoid having the database password stored in plaintext in sourcecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833/how-do-i-avoid-having-the-database-password-stored-in-plaintext-in-sourcecode)  because all of those solutions either suggested using integrated security or machine based encryption.  Neither of those options would work for me.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Don't use SQL Authorization.  Use Windows credential for the database.

Comment: Write a client-server code where the server's code can not be accesed by your clients and they can only invoke your server methods...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I avoid having the database password stored in plaintext in sourcecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833/how-do-i-avoid-having-the-database-password-stored-in-plaintext-in-sourcecode)

Comment: I can't use Windows credentials :(  I wish I could.

Comment: You could store the username and password in your sourcecode. Is there any plan to frequently change them?

Comment: @FredrikLundvall That is a terrible idea! Even once the code is compiled, it can be decompiled and you can find the raw strings.

Comment: @mason If you want to protect the username and password a little more, they can be encrypted in the sourcecode. But the issue isn't to protect the database from all possible attacks, only for users tampering with the database directly.

Comment: @FredrikLundval Credentials should *not* be stored in source code. Source code is generally stored in plain text in Source Control. That means that it's copied around to developers, stored on source control servers, possibly even made public online (github?). Credentials should be held in secure password vaults. Several of these exist already. The process which needs those credentials should then be granted those credentials at the OS level, not via a config file. There are many ways to do this, but storing the credentials in code is absolutely not one of them.

Comment: @Necoras Everything boils down to what you're trying to protect. In most cases the database could be saved in plain XML without any passwords whatsoever. The problem with this is not usally that anyone can access the data, the problem is that they can do it from outside the application (and possibly mess up logical constraints). I'm not saying that this applies to all the cases, but if the database is located in the local network and not open to outside access, I wouldn't spend much time worrying about security. If the database is located outside the network, it shouldn't be accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store passwords in plain text. Period. Full stop.

You should take a cue from SQL Server. Yes, you *can* store usernames in passwords in plain text in a web/app.config. But for Production servers you never should. Instead for Production deployments you should have a config that uses Integrated Security. That allows for elevated access by accessing credentials which are handled securely by Windows rather than insecurely in a config file.

Similarly, you should use something like [WindowsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx), or [OpenId](http://openid.net/). Then you can pass around auth tokens in your code rather than storing credentials in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

This is why software developers created multi-tier designs that include middleware services like web services. Web services can be hosted in IIS and the windows account and password can be configured into the Application Identity section of the application connection pool. Then the web.config connection string can be configured with trusted_connection=true. Configuring it this way uses the Windows Data Protection API to protect the identities.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean data at `app.config` it is simple! You have to use these two classes:

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx
And

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

I learn it from this page: [Programmatic Connection Strings in Entity Framework 6](http://www.cosairus.com/Blog/2015/3/10/programmatic-connection-strings-in-entity-framework-6) It is very good guide. In any cases, That link didn't help you!? Just Google something like this:

C# define connection string at runtime

After you put all connection string inside your code, you can go and delete any sensitive data from `connectionStrings` tag of `app.config` file because your app will not use it anymore! Then compile your code again.

If you are using DB First in EF, then you can check this Guide too: [How to set Connection String with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902496/how-to-set-connection-string-with-entity-framework)

**UPDATED:**

I added two of my Classes that I manage and create connection string with them programmatic (Dynamic), One is belong to my Entity Framework project that I used [SQL Server Compact Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) (SQL Server CE) and the second one belong to another Entity Framework Project That I used SQL Server Express 2014 with SQL Server authentication (used `sa` username). I will leave both method here in case anyone need them:

This belong to my SQL Server CE project:

```
public static string GetDBConnectionString(string dataParentPath = "")
{
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder sqlCEBuilder = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataParentPath) == true)
        dataParentPath = @"C:\MyDBFolder\CMS.sdf";

    sqlCEBuilder.DataSource = dataParentPath;
    sqlCEBuilder.Password = "12345687";
    sqlCEBuilder.MaxDatabaseSize = 4090;

    entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/CMS.csdl|res://*/CMS.ssdl|res://*/CMS.msl";
    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlCEBuilder.ToString();
    entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";

    return entityBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This belongs to my SQL Server Express project with SQL Server authentication:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CMS
{
    class mySettings
    {
        public static string GetDBConnectionString()
        {
            // **************************************************
            // This is my "ConnectionString" from App.config file.
            // <connectionStrings>
            //      <add name="CMSEntities" 
            //          connectionString=
            //              "metadata=res://*/CMS.csdl|res://*/CMS.ssdl|res://*/CMS.msl
            //                  ;provider=System.Data.SqlClient
            //                  ;provider connection string=&quot
            //                  ;data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS
            //                  ;initial catalog=CMS
            //                  ;user id=sa
            //                  ;password=12345687
            //                  ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
            //                  ;App=EntityFramework
            //              &quot;"
            //      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
            //</connectionStrings>
            // **************************************************

            string metaData = "res://*/CMS.csdl|res://*/CMS.ssdl|res://*/CMS.msl";
            string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            string dataSource = @"MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
            string databaseName = "CMS"; // = InitialCatalog
            string userID = "sa";
            string password = "12345687";
            string appName = "EntityFramework";

            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = userID;
            sqlBuilder.Password = password;
            sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = appName;


            // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
            entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;
            entityBuilder.Metadata = metaData;
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;

            return entityBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, My database in both project have same name "CMS" so its Entities will be named "`CMSEntities`". Now! **you have to override** its `DbContext` constructor. It is Important but easiest part! Better description than mine is from this page "http://www.cosairus.com/Blog/2015/3/10/programmatic-connection-strings-in-entity-framework-6":

> Now your Entity Model extends from DbContext and DbContext provides a
>   constructor to pass in a Connection String, but your Entity Model does
>   not overload those constructors for you. In order to access the
>   constructor overload, you will need to create a new class partial for
>   your Entity Model database context in the same namespace as your
>   Entity Model with the required constructor signature. Pro Tip: be sure
>   to name the filename of the cs file a different name than the Entity
>   Model database context in the event that future generated code does
>   not overwrite your changes.

So I build a class at **root** of my Project, The class must be `partial`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CMS  // Your Project Namespace
{
    public partial class CMSEntities : DbContext
    {
        public CMSEntities(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and Anytime I wanna access to my Database I will use this code:

```
    using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities(CMSSettings.GetDBConnectionString()))
    {
        // Do your DB stuff here...
    }
```

I hope It help you or others which I learn all of that from this site "stackoverflow" and users.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer.  If I did this, wouldn't the data source wizards not be able to access the database?

Comment: Nope, This methods will only use at Run time (Debugging, Release). You can try it and if you need more Info you can check out [Programmatic connection strings in entity framework 6](http://www.cosairus.com/Blog/2015/3/10/programmatic-connection-strings-in-entity-framework-6)
As I mention I use it in two projects of mine without problem. Also I encrypt my Password inside my Code too!! lol If you like you can do that for more security!

Comment: btw, Your welcome! I just learn all of that from this and other sites, I will be happy to re-share. I hope these methods help you too and If it did, please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: No, do not advocate putting passwords in source code! That's a terrible practice. You do know that someone can easily decompile the app and steal the password, right?

Comment: @Missy I do not recommend this, the password can still be recovered by anyone willing to decompile the resulting assembly/executable.

Comment: well alternatively you can Encrypt Config file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155187/securing-a-password-in-source-code

Comment: But at the end as here says:

Comment: Oh! why pressing enter send the post!!! and no edit!?! as here says: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a915daa-1355-4f85-beb3-e8910a635cdf/how-can-i-protect-password-in-source-code?forum=csharpgeneral the hacker can retrieve the encrypted data from memory when it become decrypted to use in app, so unless you are doing NSA level you need more than these methods!!?

Comment: @MRK You can structure the app so that you do not have to give the user database permissions. Read LB's comment on the question.

Comment: @mason , I cannot comment under Michael Keleher post and ask him to give us a link to a guide or tutorial about the way he talking about. (I am 39 point short! lol )  Can you please give me a link to start from it!? Thanks in Advanced